# Vue.js 2.0 v-model on ajax fetched data returns error

Tags: javascript, ajax, vuejs2

I have been struggling with this for way too long now. Vue throws an error that name is not defined. It is not defined from start but ajaxed in when Vue is created.

**clients.php**

```
<input type="text" v-bind:value="customers[<? echo $this->client['id'];?>].name">
```

**App data**

```
var app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
    customers: {},
   }
})
```

**app.js**

```
created: function(){
  // fetches clients via AJAX and places them in customer object
    this.get_clients()
}
```

> console error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

Well well well.. seems like i cracked it......

I have set a value: *clients_loaded*: false.

When ajax is succeded i set it to *true*.

In my **.php file** i can then do:

```
<template v-if="clients_loaded"> // do stuff </template>
```